# Asp.Net Core 7: DI - inject multiple instances - resolve different IOptions inside instance

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have:

```
public interface ITestService{}
```

```
public class TestService : ITestService {

    public TestService(IOptions<TestOptions> testOptions){
        // do something with testOptions.value
    }
}
```

and in appsettings.json

```
{
"TestOptions1" : {
    "Url": "something"
    },
"TestOptions2" : {
    "Url": "something"
    },
}
```

I need to be able to inject different ITestService inside controllers, different in way that i would need to be able to setup if it would use appsettings.json TestOptions1 or TestOptions2.

What is the easiest way to achieve this without too much change in code (if at all)?
Ideally i would just call in controller to use TestService("TestOptions1") or TestService("TestOptions2")

thanks!

EDIT:
is there any way to use this without changing a lot of existing code? for example, i have a lot of controllers that already use ITestService all around project, and i'd like some easy way to add new controller that uses same ITestService but that one should have different IOptions injected inside

Comment: _"I need to be able to inject different ITestService inside controllers"_  - what is the rule to determine which service should be injected?

Comment: @GuruStron there is no rule, it is just that some actions will use one service, other actions will use other service.

Answer (score 0):

You can try inject Iconfiguration and use a string paramenter to get the corresponding option.:
TestService.cs

```
    public class TestService
    {
        private TestOption testOption;
        public TestService(string option, IConfiguration configuration)
        {           
            testOption= configuration.GetSection(option).Get<TestOption>();         
            //You can use testOption.Url now
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public ValuesController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this._configuration = configuration;
        }

        [HttpGet("test")]
        public void test()
        {
            var test1 =new TestService("TestOptions1",_configuration);
            var test2 =new TestService("TestOptions2",_configuration);
        }
    }
```

Or you can also implement like this without Iconfiguration inject.

```
    public class TestService
    {
        private TestOption testOption;
        public TestService(string option) 
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();

            testOption = configuration.GetSection(option).Get<TestOption>();
        }
    }
```

Then you can use like

```
            var test1 =new TestService("TestOptions1");
            var test2 =new TestService("TestOptions2");
```

Comment: is there any way to use this without changing a lot of existing code?
for example, i have a lot of controllers that already use ITestService all around project, and i'd like some easy way to add new controller that uses same ITestService but that one should have different IOptions injected inside

Comment: @fijasko_ultimate _"and i'd like some easy way to add new controller that uses same ITestService but that one should have different IOptions injected inside"_ - so you have "the rule to determine the service to be injected"?

Comment: @GuruStron - it's not "programatical" rule like controllers from this /area or something similar - its business requirement that some controllers (actions) use other instance